# LogicApp DotLiquid string empty or null check not working as expected

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I'm using liquid templates in an Azure Standard Logic App. I have a null / empty test at the beginning of the file that is behaving differently (and weirdly) to LiquidJS and online liquid playgrounds that I test.

This is the statement:

```
{% assign itemExists = content.existing != null and content.existing.UID != null and content.existing.UID != "" -%}
```

then I use it later to generate some GraphQL:

```
{% if itemExists -%}
    _a0: updateFoo(input: {
        UID: "{{ content.existing.UID }}"
{% else -%}
    _a0: insertFoo(input: {
{% endif -%}
```

The problem is that UID is an empty string `""` and yet it's following the first `if` path, thereby producing the output:

```
    _a0: updateFoo(input: {
        UID: ""
```

I've verified that the UID is an empty string in the logic app run history.

I wrote a quick Jasmine test using exactly the same liquid file, and the same inputs from the logic app, using LiquidJS, and it works fine.

Is this a bug in DotLiquid used in logic apps? If so, how can I get around it?

### Update 1:

It only shows when you assign the test to a variable, and then try and use that variable in an `if` test. This:

```
{% assign test = "asdf" -%}
{% assign isNullOrWhitespace = test == null or test == empty %}
isNullOrWhitespace is: {{ isNullOrWhitespace }}
```

Produces `isNullOrWhitespace is: asdf` instead of the expected `isNullOrWhitespace is: false`

### Update 2:

Bug report here: https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/issues/537

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AutwqKR.png, If empty then here again  item exists contains empty string so, that is why its showing like that and considering empty string as not null, I would suggest you to assign to a variable before and then check for null and empty, hope you understand

Comment: @RithwikBojja now make the first line of your screenshot above `assign test = ""` and it will still show `The string is not empty and not null.`

Comment: Yes, you are not checking condition for itemexists, you are just checking if itemexists, that means if it contains string or empty string it will defenitely display The string is not empty and not null., so that is why i am saying to assign it before and then check the condition in next step, this is how liquid works

Comment: Sorry you've lost me...

Comment: Continue in chat? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256180/dotliquid

Comment: Given an comment in discussion and edited my answer, please cehck the edited section , The problem was with the **and** operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in Liquid if its even "" a empty string it doesnt consider as null it will consider as not null.

You can use something like below example:

If its not empty:

```
{% assign test = "Hello Rithwik Bojja" -%}
{% if test != null and test != empty -%}
  The string is not empty and not null. 
    Value:{{test}}
{% else -%}
  The string is empty or null.
{% endif -%}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

If its empty:

```
{% assign test = "" -%}
{% if test != null and test != empty -%}
  The string is not empty and not null. 
    Value:{{test}}
{% else -%}
  The string is empty or null.
{% endif -%}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

For understanding you can execute code [here](https://geekplayers.com/run-liquild-online.html)

**`Edit:`**

```
{% assign test = "Rithwik Bojja" %}
{% assign isItemExists = test | default: nil | unless: empty %}
{% if isItemExists %}
  The string is not empty and not null. 
  Value: {{ test }}
{% else %}
  The string is empty or null.
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sorry about the deleted answer + comment, have a look at my update above. You're not assigning to a variable to do your test, which is the difference.

Comment: Edited my answer please check it @thinkOfaNumber

Comment: wow what a workaround, thanks! That works, so I'll mark it as an answer and follow up on the DotLiquid github repo.